# how to move whole folder form EC2 to S3 using PHP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am learning AWS. I have a task to move the whole folder form EC2 to S3. is it possible and how?
Need some advice on it. I am able to move single file only.

Comment: If you can move a single file, then you can move a folder... that's how you move (copy) a folder into S3... you move each file individually.  It isn't clear what you're really asking.  It's also not clear what a "sholoe" is.

Comment: I have a folder named 'packages' in EC2 having 20 files. I want to move that folder to S3 using PHP. I can do it by SSH

Comment: Right, so you need to iterate through the list of files in the 'packages' directory and upload each of them to S3.

Comment: I see a method '$client->uploadDirectory('/local/directory', 'my-bucket');' but dont know how to use it and how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an answer

```
    <?php

    require("app/start.php");       

    $s3->uploadDirectory('app', 'cbtest', '', array(
        'params'      => array('ACL' => 'public-read'),
        'concurrency' => 20,
        'debug'       => true
    ));

?>
```

It is transferring whole app directory with subdirectory into S3 from EC2.